# MSBuild property being set to a value never defined (caching?)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have a .NET solution file that contains many projects, most of which are using the newer .NET SDK style `.csproj` format, but there is a project or two targeting .Net Framework 4.X and uses the older `.csproj` format.

I am extending the build process and have created 2 files in the solution root `Directory.Build.props` and `Directory.Build.targets`.

Problem: I have a particular property that is being set despite me belieiving that it shouldn't be set given the `Conditions` I have specified on my `PropertyGroup`.

To simplify the troubleshoot, I assigned a dummy starting value in my `Directory.Build.props` and then assigned a totally separate value in my `Directory.Build.targets` to see if my target ever runs.

**Directory.Build.props**

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
    <MyProperty>Not set</MyProperty> <!-- property in question -->
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Directory.Build.targets**

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup  Condition="
      '$(tf_build)' != 'true' AND 
      '$(IsInnerBuild)' != 'true' AND 
      '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' AND
      '$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)' == 'true' AND
      '$(BypassPublishLocalNugetPackages)' != 'true'">

    <MyProperty>Set</MyProperty> <!-- property in question -->
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>

    <!-- Redacted addl misc. properties ... -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="----------- BEFORE BUILD ------------"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="MyProperty: $(MyProperty)"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="GeneratePackageOnBuild = $(GeneratePackageOnBuild), UsingMicrosoftNETSdk = $(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="----------- BEFORE BUILD ------------"></Message>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="----------- AFTER BUILD ------------"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="MyProperty: $(MyProperty)"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="GeneratePackageOnBuild = $(GeneratePackageOnBuild), UsingMicrosoftNETSdk = $(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="----------- AFTER BUILD ------------"></Message>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

To my surprise, the results of the compilation from within Visual Studio are inconsistent. I can compile a handful of times and the value of `<MyProperty>` will show `Not set`, however, after additional compilations and doing something as simple as modifying the .targets file by adding a space or new line and recompiling, the results change.

**Initial compilation results**

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  ----------- BEFORE BUILD ------------
1>  MyProperty: Not set
1>  GeneratePackageOnBuild = false, UsingMicrosoftNETSdk = "
1>  ----------- BEFORE BUILD ------------
1>  MyProject -> C:\MyProject\MyProject.dll
1>  ----------- AFTER BUILD ------------
1>  MyProperty: Not set
1>  GeneratePackageOnBuild = false, UsingMicrosoftNETSdk = "
1>  ----------- AFTER BUILD ------------
```

**Random subsequent results**

*Note: Once this result below have been attained, the results do not seem to change at that point during additional compilations.*

*Also Note: The value displayed for `<MyProperty>` below is NOT the value set in my `.targets` file. That said, the condition in the `.targets` file is also not met anyway, so I'm not sure that matters.*

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  ----------- BEFORE BUILD ------------
1>  MyProperty: true
1>  GeneratePackageOnBuild = false, UsingMicrosoftNETSdk = "
1>  ----------- BEFORE BUILD ------------
1>  MyProject -> C:\MyProject\MyProject.dll
1>  ----------- AFTER BUILD ------------
1>  MyProperty: true
1>  GeneratePackageOnBuild = false, UsingMicrosoftNETSdk = "
1>  ----------- AFTER BUILD ------------
```

I've done a fair amount of playing with these files to troubleshoot. Is it possible that the value is cached somewhere? Perhaps using a value that I had set at some point in the past?

I used SysInternals' ProcMon to look to see what files are being accessed to as a clue, but nothing stood out. Restarting Visual Studio does not help.

Any ideas why I'd have some ghost value appearing in my property?

Comment: Since MSBuild is [import-order dependent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#choose-between-adding-properties-to-a-props-or-targets-file), the value of `MyProperty` in `Directory.Build.targets` file should cover the value of `MyProperty` in `…props` file. Have you tried to set Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build And Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity to `Detailed` and search in the Output window to see under which circumstance, the value has been reassigned?

Comment: Besides, I would suggest you delete the hidden `.vs` folder in your project folder and then rebuild your solution.

Comment: It appears that the issue is some sort of caching. I turned on detailed logging and despite modifying Directory.Build.targets and Directory.Build.props, old logic within these files is often retained even after saving new versions. For example: I removed my `BeforeBuild` and `AfterBuild` targets, saved the file and rebuilt one of my projects. The messages no longer printed out (as expected) HOWEVER, building any of my other projects, the messages would still print out. I performed a `clean` to no avail. I also deleted the `.vs` folder you mentioned. Still, no dice. Restart of VS.net worked

Comment: Yes, I also guess so. The specific cache may be hard to find out, but you shared a worthy solution which also gives other people a reference. I would suggest you write a new answer here and then accept it when it is available. Have a nice day.